# How to add new items to right-click event without "security warning" on click

Tags: windows, registry, right-click

I successfully add my custom item to right-click menu:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\0001MyItem]
"MUIVerb"="My test item"
"MultiSelectModel"="Player"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\0001MyItem\command]
@="myutils.exe \"%1\""
```

I have exe file from internet. If double-click on it would be "Security warning. Do you want to run this file?" message.

And if I right-click on this exe file, and choose "My test item", this message also appears! But it does not run the exe file and starts the specified handler "myutils.exe". How to get rid of this message for right-click? But I want to hold this message for double-click.

My OS is Windows 7 64.

Comment: The file is either marked as unsafe or it isn't.  You can't make it "safe for right-click but not safe for double-click".

Comment: If I create a menu item using shell dll, then when you click on it, message "Security warning" will not be! There is no difference file safe or unsafe. It is not clear why this message only occurs if I create a menu item using registry.

Comment: Presumably, because the "unsafe" flag isn't tested when a DLL is loaded, only when an executable is loaded.  I don't see that it matters; if you're running the file, you trust it, so you should unblock it.